# Как называются объекты для хранения данных (в которых только геттеры)?

Tags: php, ооп

У нас в проекте используется большое кол-во различных классов.
Часто в методах классов приходится возвращать набор каких-то данных, например:

```
return [
   'id' => ...,
   'title' => ...,
];
```

или

```
return [
   'count' => ...,
   'date' => ...,
   'price' => ...
];
```

и т.д.

Часто, несколько методов, могут возвращать одинаковый (по параметрам) набор данных.

Сейчас сталкиваемся с тем, что работать с массивами не совсем комфортно, и не регламентировано (кто-то может какой-то обязательный элемент массива не вернуть, и т.д.).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решаются подобные проблема? Что используется ?

Мы предполагаем, что надо использовать классы, а наши методы будут возвращать объект заданного класса, таким образом:

```
return new myObject(param1, param2, ...);
```

Все сводится к тому, что класс через конструктор получает список параметров, далее через геттеры сможем получать эти данные.

Хорошая ли эта практика ?

И самое главное, как называются такие объекты, которые работают только с геттерами - контейнеры ?

Comment: можно и не заморачиваться с классами, а просто сделать функцию, которая будет создавать объект и фризить его.

Comment: Как правило, классы которые хранят только параметры (свойства) называют моделями. В большинстве случая у класса нет геттеров, к ним обращаются напрямую. К примеру есть сущность в БД users, соответственно у Вас в коде будет модель Users с свойствами такими же как и в БД

Comment: Как уже правильно написали такие классы называются Моделями данных или Формы

Comment: [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO) объектами называются. Многие считают их антипатернами.